# Migration trigger not called on sign in with google

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

I am trying to migrate user from my current directory to cognito userpool. I was able to migrate user when they enter username and password, but not able to migrate when user sign in with google. I have linked google accounts with existing user in my current directory( I use email to send authentication token if user email of google account found in my directory). Same I want to do for migration. Approach I have tried

- On pre-signup trigger by external provider get users from my current directory and add it to userpool and link it with external provider. Problem is how to use same password.

Is there any better approach to migrate user on google sign in?

Comment: Third Party/Social Logins normally do not share the same password. This is something you can do programmticaly.